# Epson WorkForce WF-3640 mechanical issue during initial setup; errors 0xF1, 0xEA, 0xE8, or 0xE1, or "paper jam" with no paper in paper path

Tags: printer, epson-workforce

I'm trying to set up a brand-new Epson WorkForce WF-3640 printer and it seems there are some weird mechanical issues. It would seem the carriage is not moving freely. This is *before* I get to install the ink cartridges.

The printer may make a loud grinding noise and return errors 0xF1, 0xEA, 0xE8, or 0xE1. Alternatively, the printer may report a paper jam when there is no paper in the paper path at all.

Any ideas?

---

It seems the carriage is getting stuck on a movable plastic clip at the front right end of the unit or is not engaging correctly at the right end. Why would this be happening?

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but have you searched everywhere inside the printer for any little pieces of (maybe broken off?) packaging (polystyrene?) material?

Comment: It looks like an issue with the rail where the print heads (cartridges) move along. Check for something blocking the movement. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epson technical support stated that this is a hardware failure. Standard troubleshooting steps have not produced a solution.

The printer is being replaced under warranty.

---

**Update:** The replacement printer has been set up and is fully operational. Well, defective product is defective...

Answer (score 3):

#### 0xE8 and later 0xEA codes

> There is a blue tape on the interior that needs to be removed- once I did this it worked fine.

...

> I had the same issue: 0xE8 and later 0xEA codes. I could see that it
> was the white moving clip under the ink tank holder when on the far
> right that was catching it. The ONLY thing that fixed it was: once it
> made a noise and errored I unwillingly pushed the tank holder over to
> the left until the tanks pushed past the white clip and all the way to
> the left..
>
> Then there were no more errors.

Source [0xE8 and later 0xEA codes](http://www.askmefast.com/Epson_wf3620__need_resolution_for_error_code_0xE8-qna8892260.html#q6764814)

---

#### 520 FATAL CODE:0xF1 EPSON Workforce

> This relates to the print head not being able to completely pass from the left to right side during startup. I had a plastic carriage on the one side that was stuck in a position that stop the carriage from make the complete run from side to side. When I forced the plastic carriage down and it clicked into place the error stopped and the printer started up normally with no codes.
>
> If anything is causing the print head to not travel completely from left to right during startup, this will probable cause the code. It will be hard to see if the print head is being obstructed if you don't remove the sides.

Source [520 FATAL CODE:0xF1 EPSON Workforce](http://hpprintermanual.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/520-fatal-code0xf1-epson-workforce.html)

---

#### Print Error Code0xE3 and 0xEA

> We have seen some success with this issue by following these
> instructions. Please try this procedure one more time using the
> instructions below.
>
> 1. Turn the printer off, then disconnect the power and the interface cable. Open the cover and check for any torn or jammed paper
>    and remove it.
> 2. Reconnect the power cable and turn the printer back on.
> 3. Press the Copy button and see if the unit responds.
>
> Note: Also check that the ink cartridges and lids are pushed down
> fully.
>
> If the issue persists, the hardware itself is malfunctioning and will
> require service

Source [Print Error Code0xE3 and 0xEA](http://www.fixya.com/support/t25141495-print_error_code0xe3_0xea)

Comment: 0xEA was actually sorted out for me simply by removing a piece of blue tape which that I had missed. It was the blue piece of tape that wraps from the outside to the inside and keeps the carriage in place.

Answer (score 0):

Same error code 0xEA for WF-3640 received today.

...multiple attempts to clear it, but each time (after I finally got the carriage to go to the left), the carriage returned to the right, locked up, and error'd out.

Called Epson...cycled through the same process, even sent them a picture of the l-shaped bracket (for whatever they needed to look at)...tried again, and...surprise the same error occurred. They finally stated "hardware error", please return it to the place of purchase for a replacement. This is the first Epson in 20+ years...have had nothing but Canons and first one out of the box...it's really a shame. Hopefully the warranty replacement will be happier.

Answer (score 0):

Had 0xF1 and 0x69 errors on our Epson. Solved 0xF1 by discovering the lever on the ink carriage was open and required closing, then rebooting the machine.

0x69 was solved by re-seating the ink cartridges.

Not a good start for a brand new printer.